# django 1.9 how to automatically update context in views

Tags: javascript, django, streaming

i have context that passes a value, that value is changing as the time goes. is there anyway i can update and send the value to the test.html automatically so the user do not need to refresh the page all the time to see the new value?

```
def detail(request):

    LAST_DATA = request_data()

    context = {
        'LAST_DATA': LAST_DATA,
    }

return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

if it is not possible in views can i use javascript in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used jquery to solve the problem but i am wondering if there is way in python to fix the problem. 
this the function i used in my .html file inside template

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $( "#live" ).load( "#live" );
}, 1000); //refresh every 1 seconds
```